# How to get artist and title information using python-vlc?

Tags: python-3.x, libvlc

I'm trying to record and get song information (title and artist) from web radios using python-vlc lib.
The recording functionality is working well but the media parse to get the song information doesn't work! 
This is my code:

```
inst = vlc.Instance() # Create a VLC instance

p = inst.media_player_new() # Create a player instance
cmd1 = "sout=file/ts:%s" % outfile
media = inst.media_new("http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/JBFMAAC1.aac", cmd1)
media.get_mrl()

p.set_media(media)
p.play()

media.parse()

for i in range(13):
    print("{} - {}".format(i, media.get_meta(i)))
```

It's always returning "MediaParsedStatus.skipped" status. And all song information returns "None". I tested the same radio in VLC App and there it works fine.
Anyone can help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a stream, libvlc will not parse it by default (only local files).

You need to use a flag to tell libvlc to parse the media even if it is a network stream.

Use `libvlc_media_parse_with_options` with `MediaParseFlag` set to `network` (1).